# Difference between Erf functions

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I was evaluating some integrals and got, as part of the result, a ratio between a number and $\operatorname{erf}(c1^{c2} c3)-\operatorname{erf}(c1^{-c2} c3)$

Unfortunately, $c1^{c2} c3$ is a large number and so this difference becomes $0$, giving me a ratio of $c4/0$.

If I separately evaluate the integrals numerically, I can get the correct result, but this makes everything very slow...

Is there a way to force *Mathematica* to evaluate `Erf` in a different way?
Is there a nice approximation of `Erf` for very large and very small numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such a case, this is what the two-argument form of `Erf[]` is intended for:

```
With[{p = N[2*^3], q = N[1*^2]}, {Erf[q] - Erf[p], Erf[p, q]}]
   {0., -6.40596142491748*10^-4346}
```

Similar "arbitrary limits" functionality is also available for special functions like `Gamma[]`, `GammaRegularized[]`, `Beta[]`, `BetaRegularized[]`, `MarcumQ[]`...