# Calculation among Gamma functions

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I was calculating gamma functions in *Mathematica* while it does not give me an agreed answer.

By definition, $\Gamma[\alpha]=\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt$, $\Gamma[\alpha,z]=\int_z^\infty t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt$ and $\Gamma[\alpha,z_1,z_2]=\int_{z_1}^{z_2}t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt$. So we should have $\Gamma[\alpha]-\Gamma[\alpha,z]$ should be equal to $\Gamma[\alpha,0,z]$. But this is not the case. I simply let $\alpha=200$ and $z$ from 1 to 5, he numerical values do not fit; see below.

```
 α = 200.;
 Table[{Gamma[α] - Gamma[α, z], Gamma[α, 0, z]}, {z, 1, 5}]

{{0.*10^359, 0.00184859}, {0.*10^359, 1.0983*10^57}, {0.*10^359,6.71225*10^91},
 {0.*10^359, 2.41279*10^116}, {0.*10^359,  2.14999*10^135}}
```

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 6):

This is precisely the reason *Mathematica* supplies the three-argument form of `Gamma[]` (and `GammaRegularized[]` as well); in computing `Gamma[α] - Gamma[α, z]` for large `α`, you are effectively subtracting two large numbers to get a (comparatively) tiny result. (Similar remarks hold for computing `Cosh[x] - Sinh[x]` just to evaluate `Exp[-x]`; attempts to perform this for sufficiently large `x` are doomed.)

Thus, whenever one has to compute differences of incomplete gamma functions (as in [this recent example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191822)), think about whether it can be reformulated in terms of three-argument `Gamma[]`.

See [this related thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136018) on `Erf[]` as well.